# Cannot change the primary key in mysql 5.7.19 but can do it in mysql 5.5.56. Want to change the key anyway

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I checked this myself with the same database. The following does not work in 5.7.19 but works in 5.5.56. How to overcome this.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `primary_key` `primary_key` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial solution was dropping the foreign key constraints and re-add them after the referencing table got updated. But there were too many tables to change that way. Then I found a way to turn off constraint checking by setting "FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS" to 0. But need to set it back to the value it was having.

Comment: You do not technically have to set it back to the previous value -- this setting only affects your current connection, not the entire server, so you can just disconnect.

Comment: I changed the global value so I need to switch it back

Comment: Ah.  Yes.  Don't change the global value. Note that  `SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ...` does not set the global value, it only changes the session value.